# How to render a video html element in React with state?

Tags: reactjs

I create a state object as following:

```
this.state = {
   studentVideo: [
      {
         "identity": "Alan",
         "video": [object HTMLVideoElement]
      },
      {
         "identity": "Bob",
         "video": [object HTMLVideoElement]
      }
   ]
}
```

[object HTMLVideoElement] is a video track stream that retrieved from Twilio connection, it will show something like 
[image]

Before I use React, I just append this HTML element to the div to complete the task, but it seems that people are not suggesting me to use appendChild in React instead of conditional rendering.

So I write the following code in React:

```
                                          {
                                            this.state.studentVideo.map(
                                                (item)=>{
                                                    console.log("item value:");
                                                    console.log(item.identity);
                                                    console.log(item.video.attach());
                                                    return (
                                                        <div className="student_item" key={item.identity}>
                                                            <div>{item.identity}</div>
                                                            <div>{item.video}</div>
                                                        </div>
                                                    )
                                                }
                                            )
                                        }
```

However, once I run the following code, an error occur as following:

[image]

It seems that I cannot directly pass the html element to it, so I make little changes on it by updating the line:

```
<div>{item.video.attach()}</div>
```

to

```
<div>{item.video.attach().toString()}</div>
```

This time no error occur, but the result is not my expectation on screen:

[image]

**Question:**

So, I would like to ask how to show the video html element with React render?

---

How I add a html video element to state?
I create an empty state, and I connect to the Twilio server. Once the connection is completed, I setState with the turn by:

```
"video": track.attach()
```

Comment: How did you end up with a DOM element in your state in the first place?

Comment: Actually, I retrieve the track from Twilio, and set the state after all before doing the render.

Answer (score 0):

Twilio developer evangelist here.

When working in React it's best not to touch DOM nodes, that's why React is throwing errors for you there.

If you absolutely have to, as you do in this case using the `attach` method, then you should be using [refs](https://reactjs.org/docs/refs-and-the-dom.html). From the React docs:

> Refs provide a way to access DOM nodes or React elements created in the render method.

This is a pretty big subject, so I would recommend that you read the following blog posts that walk through creating a Video chat with Twilio and React in two different ways:

- [Building a video chat with React Hooks](https://www.twilio.com/blog/video-chat-react-hooks)
- [Building a video chat with React and class based components](https://www.twilio.com/blog/2018/03/video-chat-react.html)

Let me know if that helps at all.